# Holomorphic function and relation between its Taylor coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a function in $\mathbb{C}$,  $f(z)$, holomorphic in the half plane  $\Re(z)>2$. It is also known

$$\lim_{\Re(z) \to \infty}f(z) =1$$

Prove or disprove:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}{  \bigg|\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{f^{k+1)}(z_1)}{f^{k)}(z_1) } \Bigg| \le 1 }, \forall z_1 \mid \Re(z_1)>2$$

My approach is considering $f$ is holomorphic then it is infinitely differentiable for $\Re(z_1) > 2$ and it is equal to its own Taylor series. Then the required statement to prove is not more than the quotient of the kth and kth+1  coefficients of the Taylor series of $f$ centered on $z=z1$.

Since $\Re(z_1) > 2$ then we know the Taylor expansion of $f$ centered on $z_1$ is at least valid for $z_a= z_1 - \epsilon$. This means that the remainder $R_n(z_a)$tends to $0$ as $n$ grows.

Then, since $R_n$ tends to $0$ (It is enough to apply the limit definition, to $R_n$:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|R_{n+1}(z_a)|}{|R_n(z_a)|} \le 1 $$

But also:

$$ \frac{R_{n+1}(z_a)}{R_n(z_a)} = \frac{  \frac{1}{(k+1)!}f^{k+1)}(z_1) (-\epsilon))^{k+1}  + R_{n+2}}{ \frac{1}{k!}f^{k)}(z_1) (-\epsilon)^k +  \frac{1}{(k+1)!}f^{k+1)}(z_1) (-\epsilon))^{k+1}  + R_{n+2} }  \approx   \frac{  \frac{1}{(k+1)!}f^{k+1)}(z_1) (-\epsilon)}{ \frac{1}{k!}f^{k)}(z_1) } $$.

Mixing both expressions:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}{ \bigg|\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{f^{k+1)}(z_1)}{f^{k)}(z_1) } \Bigg|} \le \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

So this clearly proves  if $\Re(z_1) \ge 3$  as  we can take $\epsilon = 1$. But I wonder if there is a way to prove it in case $2<\Re(z_1)<3$.

Comment: I don't think the result is true. Are you sure you've stated the problem correctly?

Comment: Probably would be better to add: "Prove or disprove", because you may be totally right and the problem wrong.